# How do you access the asset folder in an unpackaged Windows SDK application?

Tags: c#, file, assets, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I added this to the csproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup> 
  <None Update="Assets/*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
  </None> 
</ItemGroup>
```

so I can access the asset folder after an install.

However, I can not find any documentation or help on how to access these files. I found this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync?view=winrt-22621
, but when I try it out, this line throws an InvalidOperationException

```cs
string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
```

Comment: How do you build the unmanaged Windows SDK application? Is this a WinUI3 C# project?

Comment: Whoops, I meant unpackaged

Answer (score 3):

I asked on the Github for WindowsAppSDK and they gave me this solution

```cs
string folder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Assets\";
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to read files in a unpackaged WindowsAppSDK test project. My files are copied to output directory with `<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>`.

```
string folderName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(App).Assembly.Location), "Assets");
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(folderName);
```

Comment: Hmmm, that is the third solution I have come across.
The cleanest solution to me looked like this
```string folder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Assets\";
```

Comment: I'm using "Assembly.Location" in all my apps because I had cases where "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" was wrong. But I agree it is cleaner !

Comment: What cases would give the wrong location?

Comment: It was old WebForms applications if my memory is good. I think this doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better and clean alternative would be this one `Package.Current.InstalledPath`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).